# Random forest: how to derive the characteristics of the predicted classes?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

Decision Trees stratify the feature space into different regions and fit a basic model to each region (average for regression, most frequent class for classification). With this method it's not difficult to derive the characteristics of the individuals falling in each predicted class or even (I'm not sure) to derive the characteristics of the group of individuals that are missed.

The problem for the decision trees is its accuracy. Random Forest can resolve this problem efficiently but is there any way to derive the 2 points above as in Decision Trees?

Comment: could you please elaborate on what you're exactly looking for? Are you looking for ways to identify the observations that are wrongly classified by a RF model?

Comment: @Antoine: Yes, exactly, the goal is to identify the observations wrongly classified and try to apply further examinations (could be manual) on them. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Does my answer below help you? Were you looking for something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you train a RF model in R on some training set (let's call it `data.train`) using [`model=randomForest(Y~., data=data.train)`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/randomForest/docs/randomForest), where Y is the column of `data.train` corresponding to the target variable, you can use the command [`predict(model)`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/randomForest/docs/predict.randomForest) to get the "out-of-bag" predictions for your model. Then, it is easy to compare whether or not the predicted class differs from the true class for each observation in the training set: something along the lines of `data.train[which(predict(model)!=Y),]` will get you all the observations (the rows of `data.train`) that were missed. Once you have this subset of your training set, you can investigate it to try to see if these observations match a particular profile (with respect to the predictor variables).

Now, if you're using cross-validation, or a separate test set, let's call it `data.test`, you can also get the predictions using `predict(model,newdata=data.test)`, and then investigate the observations for which wrong predictions were generated in the exact same way.

The "out-of-bag" (OOB) predictions are obtained as follows: any observation in `data.train` can be fed to all the trees in the Forest that were trained on boostrap samples devoid of this observation. Approximately one third (~37%) of the total number of trees will meet this condition. Further, by letting these tree vote and taking the most popular class, a prediction (the OOB prediction) can be obtained for the observation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I think I did not explain my question very well. In fact, when you say "try to see if these observations match a particular profile (with respect to the predictor variables)". Yes, my question is how to do this!

Comment: your comment above `Yes, exactly, the goal is to identify the observations wrongly classified and try to apply further examinations (could be manual) on them` let me think that identifying the variables wrongly classified was the question, because you already answered the second portion of your comment. Once you have identified the variables wrongly classified, just look at them manually.

Comment: If there are too many observations to analyze by hand, you want to look at [unsupervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning) methods. But if your question is really only about extracting insight from a data set of attributes (without target variable), then it has nothing to do with RF, and is very broad.